# Access SBT version within build?

Tags: sbt

I'd like to add a package manifest attribute to my project's *jar* file that documents the version of *SBT* that generated it. However, I can't seem to find any way to access SBT's version from within the build file.

I tried using `scala.util.Properties.propOrElse ("sbt.version", "dunno")` but I get "dunno" as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sbtVersion`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L320) setting, which according to the description

> Provides the version of sbt.

You can get the actual value via `sbtVersion.value`.

Please note you can access it only inside the task or setting macro, but if you're modifying a Manifest attribute you're very likely already doing so.